# Sublime Text 2 atualizar direto no site

Tags: sublime-text-2

Alguém sabe de uma maneira de, quando eu salvar o arquivo no Sublime Text 2, ele atualizar lá no site? Não é localhost, logo, estou sempre tendo que upar o arquivo para o servidor..

Comment: Usando o FileZilla ao clicar em um arquivo no servidor com o botão direito e selecionar editar ele irá abrir o arquivo no seu editor padrão, no caso o sublimetext, ao clicar ctrl+s o filezilla vai pedir pra upar. Porém fazer edições direto no servidor pode ser arriscado. Mas suponho que talvez o seu FTP seja no trabalho e vc faça um homeoffice, ou algo assim. Se você trabalha com mais de duas pessoas acho que você deveria pensar numa solução de versionamento como o github :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o pacote [`SFTP`](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp), para o Sublime Text 2 e 3.

Características:

- O mapeamento de uma pasta local para uma pasta remota.
- Fazer upload de arquivos, pastas ou apenas as mudanças desde seu último *commit*.
- Faz o upload de todos os arquivos abertos.
- Deleta a versão remota de um arquivo.

Porem o `SFTP` **não é gratuito**. Uma alternativa livre é o [`FTPSync`](https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync) que está disponível para o Sublime Text 2 e 3. Algumas características:

- Upload e download de múltiplos arquivos e pastas.
- Renomear ou excluir arquivos locais ou remotos.
- Determinar arquivos remotos mais recentes, sobre a proteção de gravação.

Para usa-lo basta marcar a pasta que contém os arquivos para upload no arquivo *ftpsync.settings* no seguinte formato(esse exemplo não contém todas as opções):

```all
{
    'primary': {
        host: 'ftp.mywebsite.com',
        username: 'johnsmith',
        password: 'secretpassword',
        path: '/www/',

        upload_on_save: true,
        tls: true
    }
}
```

O esqueleto pode ser simplesmente inserido indo em Preferences → Package Settings → FTPSync → *Setup FTPSync in this folder*, ou usando o menu de contexto na barra lateral ou através do atalho <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>. Veja a lista completa de configurações [**aqui**](https://github.com/NoxArt/SublimeText2-FTPSync/wiki/All-settings).